# Variance in a Bernoulli distribution.

Tags: probability, variance, bernoulli-numbers

I'm having trouble understanding the definition of variance of a Bernoulli distribution. I thought that the variance was the sum of the squared absolute values of each data point's distance from the mean divided by the number of distributions. However, I see a different definition of the variance for Bernoulli distributions:

> In general, it is useful to think about a Bernoulli random variable as
>   a random process with only two outcomes: a success or failure. Then we
>   build our mathematical framework using the numerical labels 1 and 0
>   for successes and failures, respectively. If p is the true
>   probability of a success, then the mean of a Bernoulli random variable
>   X is given by:
>
> $$ \mu = E[X] = P(X = 0) * 0 + P(X = 1) * 1 $$
>   $$ = (1   p) ⇥ 0 + p ⇥ 1 = 0 + p = p $$
>
> Similarly, the variance of X can be computed:
>
> $$ \sigma ^2 = P(X = 0)(0 - p)^2 + P(X = 1)(1 - p)^2 $$
>
> $$ p = (1 - p)p^2 + p(1 - p)^2 $$
>
> $$ = p(1 - p) \ $$

What is going on above? That doesn't seem like the standard definition of variance. Why are we taking the probability of $X = 0$ and multiplying it by the squared difference of p from 0?

Comment: The definition of variance which you have written is from the statistical point of view with data available at hand. 

What if the data being generated follows a random variable (in this example Bernoulli distribution)

The variance of a random variable $X$ is the expected value of the squared deviation from the mean of $X$. (for more https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance)

Comment: It is actually somewhat unclear where your definition of variance came from. It is not the usual sample variance calculation (which would divide by _one less than_ the number of observations), but it is not a general definition of variance for probability either. It could be population variance, or it might be how you computed variance for some random variable that had a finite number of outcomes, all equally likely.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are confusing *sample variance* with variance. Taking the average squared deviation is an *estimator* of $\text{Var}(X)$, not  $\text{Var}(X)$ itself.

Variance is defined as
$$
\mathbb E[(X-\mu)^2]
$$
where $\mu = \mathbb E [X]$. In the case of Bernoulli $\mu = p$, so you immediately get 
$$
\mathbb E[(X-p)^2] = \mathbb P(X = 0)(0-p)^2 + \mathbb P(X = 1)(1-p)^2
$$